# Amazon Web Services - Length of HostIds returned

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm making a platform that requires allocating hosts programatically. The API returns a HostId, that's a string. (Source: [boto3 docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.allocate_hosts)). If anyone has experience dealing with AWS, could you tell me if this string has a constant length? And if it does, how long is it?
This is from the perspective of designing a database - specifically for setting a maximum length to the field. I don't want to assign the host ids superfluous space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [december 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/theyre-here-longer-ec2-resource-ids-now-available/) aws has moved to a new format which is a resource identifier followed by a 17-character string.

Each resources have their own prefix, for example:

- instance is `i-xxxx....`
- an EBS snapshot is `snap-xxxx....`
- reserved instances are `r-xxx....`
- ...

Comment: I found that too, but what's the length of the resource identifier?

Comment: depends of the resource, instance is `i-` snapshot is `snap-` ... its a case by case

Comment: Alright, I'll keep it at 30 just to be safe. Thank you!